# Have you employed any strategies or techniques to overcome user resistance when implementing a new system?

Tags: usability

We have been trying now for a while to assist the management (of a customer) with the implementation of a a new system that is custom developed by ourselves, to their requirements. Their old system is text based (DOS) and their employees have been using it for years. The new system is Windows GUI and have many advanced features which will make their lives easier and their organisation more efficient. The problem is that the staff do not want to adapt to the new GUI environment and they are now resorting to be unfriendly and as unhelpful as possible, often placing serious obstacles in our way. The management is adamant that implementation must proceed. The system runs trouble free. We have been consistently friendly and helpful with all parties.

Any advise would be greatly appreciated! Have you encountered something like this before and did you manage to turn it round?

Note:This question is intended to help Programmers etc. with implementation difficulties by sharing experiences and factual solutions that worked. It is not intended to be subjective and indeed Programming techniques may help to solve the problem.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

### Use the tool

Somebody needs to **really** understand how the existing tool works. Not just well enough to walk through it; but well enough to **do it for real**. Why not take 2 weeks and go and do their job with them? That will both improve your understanding of the tool, and may foster a better working relationship with them. And while you're there, perhaps buy the drinks once or twice - it sounds corny, but anything that lowers the hostility, and lets you communicate.

### User experience

Getting a **good** developer (or better: designer) who understanding user-experience is probably key. You can't just completely change their tooling and expect their productivity to remain the same.

### Keyboard use:

Think of tools like Visual Studio, AutoCAD, etc - in most cases you don't need the mouse, and "die hard" types wouldn't notice if you took their mouse away. Try to respect this; provide shortcuts / chords (ideally the same as the existing system).

### Terminology:

Keep it the same. Don't invent new terms for things.

### Talk to them?

This may or may not be possible, but getting a few **key** users "on board" early can be pivotal; especially if you ***genuinely*** empower them to help with the user experience.

### Find the faults

In the existing system. Take away their existing pain points and they may forgive you a lot.

Comment: Also, how about trying to get them to list all the things they 'hate' about the new system and then change a couple of the easier things right away. There's bound to be something easy like a button in the wrong place or something. Once they've seen you make a change for them there's a good chance they'll be less negative and the feedback you get will be more useful.

Comment: Regarding "Use the tool", another option usability professionals often use is ethnography, or a fly-on-the-wall approach- http://www.usabilityfirst.com/glossary/term_309.txl

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately it sounds like a case of needing to close the barn doors after the horses have bolted.  You really need to get grass roots buy-in on the need for an improved system before beginning the project and maintain that relationship during the development.

By having champions of the system at the "coal face" level in the business would a) make sure you meet not only the management requirements but also the users goals which is all important in a successful system and b) the users get a system to which they have been a development party not just had a system thrust on them.

Getting people to moan about the short comings of an existing system is easy.  Describing possible new systems before its create in way which allows the users to comment enables them to feel some control and gives you vital feedback.  Be absolutely sure to identifier those killer gripes about the old system and make sure those are addressed in the new system.

Of course this all a bit late for you.  The way forward is to create a review forum with the most vocal opponents and put them in a room with you and management.  Get them to defend their reasons for not wanting the new system.  If you can't show how your new system is better then perhaps it isn't.  If you can see how the new system might be slightly improved (the movement may only need to be small) then do that, it may go a long way to get back the feeling of involvement you missed out on before.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I think some of their attitude relates to hardware that is old and slow, more than system functionality since they cannot pinpoint anything wrong with the system. They do not have enough funds now to upgrade the clients after upgrading the server.

Comment: Your comment above "The system runs trouble free" is a bit misleading if you're now saying that the hardware is too slow. 

Are performance issues the main problem? If so that is a big problem, do you use the system in your testing on the same hardware?

Comment: The problem is that the hardware is somewhat slow. We cannot determine what the user's exact problem is - to us it seems like a "cultural" thing or just a simple "unwillingness to change" and there may be internal organisational politics in the mix aas well.

Answer (score 2):

I would sit together with the staff or a couple of the more loud mouthed opposers, go through what they find lacking with the system and suggest some of these changes to be incorporated in a future release(s). That way they will pay more attention to your the system and also feel more a part of the process instead of just being handed something like some peon. In addition it would also help avoid any misunderstandings about the system.

Answer (score 1):

Get one / more of the user to be your champion by involving them in the development process.  Make sure to choose the right ones.  Hopefully one that you can reason with.  When launching, do a launch event.  Make it a big deal.  Not necessarily applied to an application, but I've seen it worked in my previous work environments.  If this is too late (you went ahead without any involvement from the actual users before), well... there is always things called staff turnover, lol.  Out with the old and in with the new.  Make the new users your buddy :).

Comment: We have a user champion and he is very eager - he was always positive to the new system. I think they (other users) all want to be champions but have opted to be negative in the beginning and it is now difficult for them to cross the divide.

Comment: Give Anders' suggestion a try.  Be diplomatic.  Ask them why they are so negative and maybe you can find out and start working together to resolve this.

Answer (score 1):

It is sad that software often gets replaced by a management decision without any user involvement and then people wonder why the system is rejected.

I've witnessed this first hand. A guy I once worked was told to develop a new version of an application "in secret". At the end of 6 months development it was shown to the users. It didn't meet their requirements and they were angry they hadn't been involved. Needless to say the software didn't make it into production and the developer left shortly after (I felt sorry for him as he had wasted 6 months effort and actually did a real good job considering the circumstances).

The chances are that the software is inferior to the previous application- perhaps data entry is actually slower (you will be biased as you wrote it- everyone likes to think their software is better).

Re-engage with the users, do some analysis and work out what is bad about the old system. If the new system can address the grips the users have with the old system you might be able to turn this around.

Edit- who was involved in engaged with your developers? Presumably the managers at the client, who probably never use the system? This is another big mistake people tend to make- managers driving requirements.

If the old system is perfect, then it never needed to be replaced in the first place!

Comment: The (custom) system is based on our application that is used by many of our existing and happy customers. We did involve the users, but they expressed no interest in anything new.

Comment: Ah OK. How did you assess that your solution was better? Did you measure task completion times on both systems? Perhaps looking into something like the Keystroke-Level Model would be a good idea- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/KLM_%28human_computer_interaction%29

Comment: Well, we demonstrated our existing system, management and (a then user champion) was deligted and gave us their specs for changes. We then got their go-ahead (after changes was developed), including user involvement and then attempted to initiate implementation on completion. Assesment that our system is what they wanted was based on customer decision.

Answer (score 1):

You have to show some kind of benefit for making the change. A demo / mockup can be useful for this. Choose a manager to demo it to and wait. Let it become his idea. Then it might move forward. Being to pushy can cause a negative knee-jerk reaction which might block further consideration of the idea.

Comment: The organisation is relatively small, management is all for it, but the users not.

Comment: Sorry, didn't read the question carefully enough! I guess you'll have to show how much easier it will make their work. Shame things are turning nasty. Makes communication more difficult.